# How can I change the system font?

Tags: 15.10, fonts, system, unity-tweak-tool

I googled and I got nowhere- the unity tweak tool doesn't show the font I installed (that I really, really, want)
Can anyone help? The font name is Raleway

Comment: How did you install the Raleway font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the fonts to be installed for all users in the system then create a directory under `/usr/share/fonts` and place these new fonts in them. If it's just for a single user account place the font files in ~/.fonts/ directory. Then issue these commands as sudo.

```
mkfontscale
mkfontdir
fc-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just copy the `.ttf` files for the font you want into the `~/.fonts/` directory, the unity-tweak-tool will be able to find them (although logging out and logging back in might be necessary for that directory to be indexed).